# Buffered I/O in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, chicken-scheme

Racket has the nice `read-bytes-async!` function, which I believe exists in every other programming language in the world. It reads what it can from an input stream, without blocking, into a buffer, returning the number of bytes written.

Said function seems like an absolutely essential function for efficiently implementing, say, the Unix `cat` tool, yet Chicken Scheme seems to lack any such function. Of course, I can use `(read-byte)` and `(write-byte)`, but that is slow and eats up all my CPU.

Even `(copy-port)` seems to not have any such implementation. Instead, before the stream is closed, the data is copied buffer-by-buffer only when the buffers fill. This means that `(copy-port (current-input-port) (current-output-port))` does not behave like `cat` at all.

Am I just suffering from a terrible blind spot in reading the documentation, or does Chicken shockingly actually lack such a function? So `cat` can't even be written efficiently in Chicken?

Comment: It could well be outdated, but [this mailing list post from 2005](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.scheme.chicken/2075) mentions that "currently I/O from stdio and files is fully blocking."

Comment: Anyways, I am deleting this question. The `posix` library has a low-level function that does what I want. The mailing list post indeed seems to be very outdated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed my problem. The `posix` library has the `file-read` function that does what I want, albeit on a file descriptor. Fortunately, ports in Chicken are just thin wrappers around file descriptors; there is a port to file descriptor converter in the `posix` library as well.

Interestingly, these functions work on Windows as well. `posix` seems to not be limited to POSIX systems.

Comment: So this can be used to, for example, do a non-blocking read on STDIN?

Comment: It behaves like the Unix/most-other-langs read(). That is, wait until there is data available, and read the available data into the buffer, returning the length of data read. Chicken's default I/O does something bizarre: it waits until the entire buffer is full before returning. This makes implementing most `cat`-like programs impossible.

Comment: I _recently_ figured out a way to do what you're describing using external C functions for file i/o: via Chicken's amazing C-interfacing abilities.

Answer (score 2):

as you said the posix unit is the key ,but to your question what seems more relevant is [set-buffering-mode!](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20posix#setting-the-file-buffering-mode)

this applies to any port.

Comment: No, that is not related to what I want. I was meaning using my own buffer, not the port buffers. Even when the ports are buffered, doing the copy char-by-char is really slow.

Comment: what if you used byte-blob-read from http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/byte-blob  ?